# Feasibility of hiding some of the phone icons upon running an app

Tags: android, iphone

I am a student and working on a school project. At the moment I am in the research phase. Part of the idea I came up with is to run an app on the phone to hide some of the other icons such as phone call icon, message icon, camera icon etc.

I wanted to know if this idea is feasible. I was wondering if you could give me some tips or point me to a website so that I could post such questions.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, **you cannot do this on iPhone**.

Maybe someone else will tell you the Android case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fattie. Do you know why? Is that a restriction that ios have like it does not allow to mess up with its icons?

Comment: correct.  apps are "sandboxed" in iOS.  it's absolutely **impossible to affect another app in any way**.  you can't even (as a rule) communicate with other apps, so, there's no chance you could hide/etc icons.  good luck!